# BroadcastReceiver on Huawei MediaPad 7 Youth 2 not receiving

Tags: android

so i have this problem. My application has a service that should start with the device, on restart or boot. So i have written BroadcastReceiver that reacts on those events:

```
<receiver
        android:name="some.random.package.BackgroundBroadcastReceiver"
        android:process=":m_broadcast_receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And added the needed permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

This receiver works great with every device i have tested (over 20 phones and 5 tablets). Until Huawei MediaPad 7 Youth 2 ...

When i start the application everything works great, the service is starting, the receiver is receiving ... but when the device is restarted, the receiver stops working. Like i said, so far this happens only on this tablet.

Any suggestions?